# How to get attribute value of of the immediate parent of a clicked element

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to get attribute value of the immediate parent of a clicked anchor. Any ideas on how I can achieve this. My code looks like below:

**HTML**

```
<div class="perTalk" catch="1">
  <div>Content one</div>
  <a href="#" ng-click="idVal()">Reply</a>
</div>
<div class="perTalk" catch="1.1">
  <div>Content two</div>
  <a href="#" ng-click="idVal()">Reply</a>
</div>
<div class="perTalk" catch="1.2">
  <div>Content three</div>
  <a href="#" ng-click="idVal()">Reply</a>
</div>
```

**AngularJS**

```
 var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

          app.controller('../scripts/sleek-angular-control', function ($scope) {
            $scope.idVal = function () {

                var catchVal = $(this).closest(".perTalk").attr("catch"); 

                $scope.firstname = catchVal;
                $scope.lastname = "Doe";

            }
        });
```

Comment: whats the source of your attribute value ? is there a parent controller ?

Comment: just post the corresponding html pls - because i think you don't understand the angularjs way here. Including the place where you call your idVal function

Comment: the question is - why don't you write `<a href="#" ng-click="idVal(1)">Reply</a>` and pass it to your function `$scope.idVal = function (catchVal) { ... }` ?

Comment: @SleekGeek : I think you need to explain better. Do you mean that, when you click on `<div class="perTalk" catch="1.1">` ,  you want to get `1` which is the value `catch="1"` ???  can u create a working demo on plunkr.com , so that we can look into the use case. I get this feeling that you are over doing some simple stuff

Comment: @ShashankVivek Yes, I want to get the value of the attribute "catch" and use it as the value for "catchVal"